Как вывести записи всех подкатегорий через сводную таблицу
Сейчас вывожу записи конкретной категории на которую перехожу, а вот как вывести записи всех подкатегорий?
При этом использую сводную таблицу
Companies | Categories | Company_category
Подкатегории вывожу через parent_id
Сейчас код выглядит вот так:
$companies = Company::search(request('search'))->query(function(Builder $query) use($category){
    $query->select(['id', 'name', 'company_type_id', 'logo'])
    ->when($category->exists, function(Builder $query) use($category){
        $query->whereRelation(
            'categories',
            'categories.id',
            '=',
            $category->id
        );
    })
    ->sorted()
    ->companyByCity();
})->paginate(15);

Category Model
    public function companies(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class, 'category_company');
}

public function categories(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
}

public function childrenCategories(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class)->with('categories');
}

public function parent(): belongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'id');
}

Company Model
public function categories(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'category_company');
}


Как вы в Laravel  написали модели? Дайте исходники моделей компаний и категории.

Добавил модели!

Да и еще по вашему запросу как то не понятно. что у вас есть и что хотите вывести. Пожайлуста проесните, вводные параметры, и что нужно вывести.

Есть база компаний, каждая компания может быть связанна с одной и более категориями. Связываю через сводную таблицу category_company.
При клике на материнскую категорию (т.е. эта категория имеет одну и более подкатегорий) необходимо показать все компании этой категории, в том числе и компании подкатегорий.
Такой принцип сейчас в любом магазине есть.
@Raz Galstyan

Выше упамянут ответ. Там при момощи этого запроса можно вывести все подкатегории заданной категории.
При помощи этого запроса можно сделать так.
Сперва нам нужно взять все id категорий которые нам нужны.
$categoryIds = DB::select("
        with recursive cte (id, parent_id)
             as (
                 select     id,
                            parent_id
                 from       categories
                 where id = $parentCategoryId
                 union all
                 select     categories.id,
                            categories.parent_id
                 from       users
                 inner join cte on categories.id = cte.parent_id
             )
        select * from cte;
    ")->pluck('id')->toArray();

После того как у нас уже есть все ид категорий которые нам нужны, уже можете по такому запросу извлеч все что в этих категориях.
$companies = Company::query()
    ->where('field_name', $search)->whereHas('categories', 
          function($query) use($categoryIds) {
              $query->whereIn('category_id', $categoryIds)
          })->get();


У такого подхода один минус, при большом объеме данных более 50 000 записей, запрос долго отрабатывает (2-3 секунды). Если получаем компании из материнской категории в которой к примеру 2000 записей, то запрос отрабатывает довольно быстро

@АнтонЧехов Если у вас структура базы хорошое. и добавлены FK то так долго не будет обработка.
Нужно создать базу правильно.

@АнтонЧехов
Во всяком случае обработку база делает намного быстрее, если сделать правильный 1 запрос, чем много запросов к базе.
